# How do I request a client certificate when a call is made to Swagger UI / Swashbuckle?

Tags: certificate, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0, swashbuckle

I have an internal site that I have created that uses Swagger UI / Swashbuckle.  The API requires a client certificate, but when I click the "Try it now!" button it doesn't pop up the browser UI to request a client cert.  How would I add a client cert request to the UI so that it is submitted with the API request?

Comment: Have you ever found an answer to this?

Comment: No, never did.  Ended up working around it, but so long ago I forget how I did it.  :s

Comment: Fair enough :) I see they've made some progress on the code so it appears it's possible to present a clientside certificate.

Comment: Mjh (or anyone),  Where do you see that?  I mean where do you see that Swagger can connect to an endpoint that is requiring a client certificate?

Comment: Any update on this? Anyone found a way to make swagger request a cert?